# Why google shows categories description only in some countries?

Tags: wordpress, seo

The thing is I have to make a website shown the categories description (wordpress) when searching the word 'esika' in google.

The website is from Peru and searching 'esika' from google.com.pe shows the official website first position but with categories in small without description. The same for countries like Chile, Ecuador

[image: From Peru]

If I search the same thing 'esika' y Google Spain google.es, I get the official website first position but with the categories with their descriptions. The same happens with lots of other countries like Canada, Venezuela, Ecuador, France...

[image: From Spain]

What makes it different? How can I do google peru to show those descriptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "categories description" that you are referring to are known as **Sitelinks** and according to [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en):

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.
>
> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to
>   improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster
>   input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however,
>   to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's
>   internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's
>   informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

Now as the process is 'automated' there isn't any need to worry about. Google Peru might be using some different data center where the sitelinks have still not propagated.

All you need to do is to wait or simply ignore this issue as it might also be happening in other localized Google Searches (a common insignificant issue).